# Question about write hashCode when HashCode are equal, but the probability of two element are not equal

Tags: java, dictionary, hashcode

I am working on an ADT(Abstract Data Type) FMap. I have finished overriding the equals method. Now I need to work on HashCode. But I am a little bit confused with the instructions.

If m1 and m2 are values of the FMap ADT, and

```
    ! (m1.equals(m2))



then m1.hashCode() is unlikely to be equal to m2.hashCode().
```

Note:  The word "unlikely" will be interpreted as follows. For every type K and V, if both m1 and m2 are selected at random from a set of FMap values such that for every non-negative integer n and int value h the probability of a randomly selected FMap m having

n == m.size() is

```
P(n) = 1/(2^(n+1))
```

and for each key k such that m.containsKey(k) the probability that

```
     h == k.hashCode() is at most 1/5
```

and for each value v such that v.equals(m.get(k)) the probability that

```
     h == v.hashCode() is at most 1/5
```

and the three probabilities above are independent

then the probability of m1.hashCode() == m2.hashCode() when m1 and m2 are not equal is less than 40%.

I am very confused about this part....